# How to set line thickness for interaction plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following `R` code which plots my interaction:

```
 interaction.plot(plotable$Condition, plotable$Scenario, plotable$value ,
             xlab=deparse(substitute(Condition)),
             ylab='Mean m',
             col=2:8,
             trace.label=deparse(substitute(Scenario)))
```

How do I set the line thickness of the plot?

Comment: Try `lwd`, and reading `par` for a general list of graphical arguments. Many base plotting functions accept many (but not all) of these via `...`.

Comment: thanks, `lwd` worked.